# Laravel .gitignore blocking of generated css and js files(from `npm run *` type commands) is not effective, as it's supposed to be

Tags: bash, git, gitignore, git-bash, git-for-windows

I am working in Laravel 5.6.*(probably latest in 5.6 line) project, where I just found that the `npm run dev` command generated bunch of CSS & JS files into `/public/css` and `/public/js` paths respectively.

When I try to block those files from being detected by Git, thro' .gitignore like below, it still gets detected, why this unexpected behavior ?:

.gitignore trial 1:

```
/public/css
/public/js
```

.gitignore trial 2:

```
public/css/*
public/js/*
```

I haven't edited the GitBash version(2.14.*, Windows 10) I am using, so I suppose both the above syntax should work, but they both aren't, can anyone help out ?

Comment: `public/css/` and `public/js/`?

Comment: I suppose this is hardly relevant, I am starting GitBash as admin, but I change into project directory and then only run `git status`. Also once I change `.gitignore`, I don't think there's any need to close and re-open the GitBash into the same directory, is there ?

Comment: No need to restart bash after changing the `.gitignore` file

Comment: tried your first suggestion and that works, wanna supply the output of `git status`